# Values mixing between parameters problem in C++ (Codeblocks)

Tags: c++

enter code hereI'm trying to make something in c++ Codeblocks using GCC/G++/GFortran compiler and GDB debugger from MinGW-W64 project and something weird is happening. The values got mixed between parameters.(front1[0] takes the value of idk[0]).I tried to change the names of the parameter but same happens. What I should do??

The code:

```
 char idk[0],front1[0],front2[0],front3[0],front4[0]; 
 front1[0]='*';front2[0]='*';front3[0]='*';front4[0]='*'; cout<<endl; cout<<" 
 front:"<<front1[0];idk[0]=' ';cout<<" front:"<<front1[0]<<endl; cout<<endl;
```

The console output:

```
front:* front:
```

Comment: Don't post images of code. It's hard to copy it down

Comment: you use arrays of 0 elements ?

Comment: char idk[0],front1[0],front2[0],front3[0],front4[0];

front1[0]='*';front2[0]='*';front3[0]='*';front4[0]='*';
cout<<endl;
cout<<" front:"<<front1[0];idk[0]=' ';cout<<" front:"<<front1[0]<<endl;
cout<<endl;

Comment: I'm using the 0 element

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Please [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text. All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text, please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: @TheReaper  you confuse the size and the max index, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you defined arrays of **0** elements, you need arrays of 1 element to be able to use the index 0 without undefined behavior.

Do not confuse the size and the value of the higher index which is the size minus 1

So

```
char idk[1], front1[1], ...
```

to *define* arrays of 1 character, and for instance

```
front1[0]='*';
```

to set the first (and alone) element of *from1* to the character star

Anyway to have an array of 1 element is complicated for nothing and can be replaced by

```
char idk, front1, ...
```

and then for instance

```
front1 = '*';
```

---

Out of that in for instance

```
front1[0]=''
```

`''` is not a valid literal character because the character is missing

---

Example :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char idk[1],front1[1],front2[1],front3[1],front4[1]; 
  
  front1[0]='*';
  front2[0]='%';
  front3[0]='$';
  front4[0]='!'; 
  cout<<endl; 
  cout<<" front:"<<front1[0];
  idk[0]=' ';
  cout<<" front:"<<front1[0]<<endl;
  cout<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -Wall a.cc 
a.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cc:6:8: warning: variable ‘idk’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   char idk[1],front1[1],front2[1],front3[1],front4[1];
        ^~~
a.cc:6:25: warning: variable ‘front2’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   char idk[1],front1[1],front2[1],front3[1],front4[1];
                         ^~~~~~
a.cc:6:35: warning: variable ‘front3’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   char idk[1],front1[1],front2[1],front3[1],front4[1];
                                   ^~~~~~
a.cc:6:45: warning: variable ‘front4’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   char idk[1],front1[1],front2[1],front3[1],front4[1];
                                             ^~~~~~
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out

 front:* front:*

pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: I changed the it, now I'm using arrays of 1 elements, and now idk takes the value of front1

Comment: @TheReaper are you sure to changed **all** sizes from 0 to 1 ? are you using only index 0 ?

Comment: @TheReaper that's still not the best way. Just use chars, as bruno said.

Comment: char idk[1],front1[1],front2[1],front3[1],front4[1];

front1[1]='*';front2[1]='*';front3[1]='*';front4[1]='*';
cout<<endl;
cout<<" front:"<<front1[1];idk[1]=' ';cout<<" front:"<<front1[1]<<endl;
cout<<endl;

Comment: @TheReaper the indexes must be **0** not 1, only the sizes must be 1

Comment: Using this code idk[1] takes the value of front1[1], so " " becomes "*"

Comment: @TheReaper do understand the difference between a size and an index ? you want `char idk[1],front1[1],front2[1],front3[1],front4[1]; front1[0]='';front2[0]='';front3[0]='';front4[0]=''; cout<<endl; cout<<" front:"<<front1[0];idk[0]=' ';cout<<" front:"<<front1[0]<<endl; cout<<endl; `

Comment: Yes I understood, but the thing aren't working correctly yet

Comment: @TheReaper perhaps you execute your program in an IDE and because of that you don't get the expected outputs, execute your program by hand in a terminal

Comment: Between the '    '  are * from the beginning, but idk why when I posted the code the * got deleted

Comment: char idk[1],front1[1],front2[1],front3[1],front4[1];

front1[0]='*';front2[0]='*';front3[0]='*';front4[0]='*';
cout<<endl;
cout<<" front:"<<front1[0];idk[0]=' ';cout<<" front:"<<front1[0]<<endl;
cout<<endl;

if(rt==2) {front1[0]='-';front3[0]='/'; fstream Angry("Angry", fstream::in);Angry>>front2[0];front4[0]='|';}

if(rt==3) {cout<<endl<<"Background:"<<endl<<" ";gets(idk);cout<<"Foreground:"<<endl<<" ";gets(front1);
front2[0]=front1[0];front3[0]=front1[0];front4[0]=front1[0];}

Comment: Now the other characters/parameters like front4 and front1 aren't changing their vales correctly

Comment: @TheReaper the `*` is a special character used to write italic, it must be quoted as I did at the beginning of that remark

Comment: @TheReaper I again edited my answer to put a full example where the execution is the expected one. All is ok for you now ?

Comment: Yes, thx very much